# jquery is not working properly syntax error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

Hi all I am using the jquery for the lightbox effect popup for wordpress. I tried in Wamp Server is working fine (localhost), But Today Only we didn't get any output from jquery i checked with the console of firebug its throws syntax error i am not sure what i did mistake i provide you the code you can review it and tell me where i did mistake.

```
<script type="text/javascript">



jQuery(document).ready(function($){

if(jQuery.cookie('popup_user_login')!='yes'){

<?php if ($_COOKIE['test']!='5') {?>

jQuery('#ptechsolfb').delay(<?php echo get_option('popup_template_delay');?>).fadeIn('medium');<?php 

   if(get_option('popup_delay_auto')=='1') { ?> function countDown(i) {

             var int = setInterval(function () {

           document.getElementById("ptechsolin").innerHTML =  "You Must Wait Until the Timer Ends " + i;



        i-- || clearInterval(int) || jQuery('#ptechsolfb').stop().fadeOut('medium') ; 

         //if i is 0, then stop the interval

    }, 1000);

}

countDown(<?php echo get_option('popup_template_count');?>);





<?php } ?> <?php if(get_option('close_esckey_ed')=='1') { ?>

     jQuery(document).bind('keydown', function(e) { 

        if (e.which == 27) {

            jQuery('#ptechsolfb').stop().fadeOut('medium')

        }

    });<?php }?><?php if(get_option('close_externel_click')=='1') {?>jQuery('#ptechsolfb').click(function(){jQuery('#ptechsolfb').stop().fadeOut('medium');<?php } ?><?php if(get_option('popup_template_close')=='1') {?> jQuery('#fbclose').click(function(){jQuery('#ptechsolfb').stop().fadeOut('medium');<?php }?><?php } ?>})     }jQuery.cookie('popup_user_login','yes',{path:'/',expires:<?php echo (get_option('popup_plugin_template_cookies')); ?>})

});
</script>
```

Here is the Screenshot of what i saw in console of firebug. 
[image: Error in Javascript]

Is this is the problem why the jQuery is not Loading properly. Any Suggesstion Would Be Much Appreciated.

Here is the [Working Site Example](http://techstumbling.com)
Thanks,
vicky

[image: NetBeans Error]

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    if (jQuery.cookie('popup_user_login') != 'yes'){



    jQuery('#ptechsolfb').delay(100).fadeIn('medium');
            function countDown(i) {

            var int = setInterval(function () {

            document.getElementById("ptechsolin").innerHTML = "You Must Wait Until the Timer Ends " + i;
                    i-- || clearInterval(int) || jQuery('#ptechsolfb').stop().fadeOut('medium');
                    //if i is 0, then stop the interval

            }, 1000);
                    }

    countDown(25);
            jQuery(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {

    if (e.which == 27) {

    jQuery('#ptechsolfb').stop().fadeOut('medium');
    }

    });
            jQuery('#ptechsolfb').click(function(){jQuery('#ptechsolfb').stop().fadeOut('medium'); }); jQuery('#fbclose').click(function(){jQuery('#ptechsolfb').stop().fadeOut('medium'); });jQuery.cookie('popup_user_login', 'yes', {path:'/', expires:0})

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Joe I tried that here is the edited stuff I am Not sure here is the error that i got while using netbeans

Comment: I tried that too Still the Error On Editor Came Up

Comment: I edited the Last code Which I changed based on your suggestion

Comment: See Your Answer is correct But Still I getting the error on eof Unexpected error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude you really missed a "});".

Where is the close of the opened "{" in your second line

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

Cheers...  :P

Comment: I tried that too Even it doesn't work on localhost but it working in live Localhost is Wamp Server Live is Linux Is this causing a problem

Comment: Dude there is something wrong with balancing "}", you can use notepad++ or any other respected editor to trace them.